# jQuery find next input field in Table for calculation

Tags: jquery

I currently have the following table layout, which can be dynamically extended by the user by clicking on a button:

```
          <tr>
              <td><input type="number" name="amount[]" size="4" value="" min="1"/></td>
                <td>x</td>
              <td><input type="hidden" name="seats[]" value="" /></td>
          </tr>
```

Now, when I leave the amount field, I want jquery to go there and multiply each amount field by the corresponding seats field and calculate to total.
I have tried this as follows, unfortunately it does not work.

```
$('input[name^="amount"]').focusout(function(){
  var total = 0;
  var seats = 0;
  $('input[name^="amount"]').each(function() {
    total = total + ($(this).val() * $('input[name^="amount"]').parent().next().find('input').val());
  });
alert(total);
});
```

Comment: the `seat` is not an `input` tag, you can not find it by `.find('input')`

Comment: @JackTing Sure looks like an <input> to me

Comment: O... sorry, there is another `<td>x</td>` between these 2 input field, you need one more `next()` before `find()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('input[name^="amount"]').focusout(function(){
  var total = 0;
  var seats = 0;
  $('input[name^="amount"]').each(function() {
    total = total + ($(this).val() * $(this).parent().next().next().find('input').val());
  });
alert(total);
});
```

You can have a more general solution.

```
$('input[name^="amount"]').focusout(function(){
  var total = 0;
  var seats = 0;
  $('input[name^="amount"]').each(function() {
    total = total + ($(this).val() * $(this).parents('tr').find('input[name^="seats"]').val());
  });
alert(total);
});
```

Comment: Have another table like this: `<tr>
                    <td><div class='col-xs-1'><input type='number' max='5' name='amount[]' min='0'  style='width: 35px!important;'></div></td>
                    <td>x</td>
                    <td>5 Sitzplätze <input type='hidden' name='seats[]' value='5'</td>
                    <td><span style='color: #28aa46;'>(noch 5x verfügbar)</span></td>
                  </tr>` tried the same but get NaN from jQuery, can you help me again

Comment: see the second part.